# Where in the Property Sheet Window Can I Define the Label Parent in Access/VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to attach a label to a textbox and I'd like to know where in the property sheet I can do it or how to do it.

I'd like to share this code for manipulation of parent/child controls:

```
Private Sub Comando15_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    Dim ctl As Control
    
    For Each ctl In Me.Form.Controls
        With ctl
            If .ControlType = acLabel Then
                If .Parent.Name <> Me.Form.Name Then
                    MsgBox "Controle Pai: " & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & .Parent.Name & Chr(13) + Chr(10) + Chr(10) & _
                        "Controle Filho: " & Chr(13) + Chr(10) & .Name
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next ctl
    
Exit_Handler:
    Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error No: " & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you creating the textbox in Form Design or through some VBA code? If it's in code, can you add that to your question and tell us what's not working?

Comment: I'm creating it in the form design. do you know which field in the property sheet is used to define a label as child of a textbox, for instance? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow! I found it! in order to attach a label to a textbox, open the form in the design view and select both label and textbox. a small warning box (with an exclamation and a dropdown button) will appear. just click on the button and select the option "attach lable_name to textbox_name". simple like that.

thanks Mark for your quick reply.